# Name for words without squared symbols

Tags: reference-request, fl.formal-languages, combinatorics

Is there a common name in combinatorics for words that do not have square of size 1 ? That is words such that no symbols appears twice in a row or, more formally, words *not* in $\bigcup_{s\in\Sigma} \Sigma^* s s \Sigma^*$ where $\Sigma$ is our alphabet.

Comment: I propose calling the occurrence of a repeated letter a “hiccup” and correspondingly calling your language hiccup-free.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would call them *stutter-free* words, since there is the notion of *stutter-invariant language*, which is already well-known.